# OrderByDescending linq query

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to show deal.type as decending order by date but I cannot get the result to show in Descending order.

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
    [HttpGet]
    [Queryable(PageSize = 10)]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] Query query)
    {
        var data = db.database_ICs.AsQueryable();

        if (query.price_type != null)
        {
            data = data.Where(c => c.Cover == query.price_type);
        }
        if (query.deal_type != null)
        {
            data = data.Where(c => c.Type == query.deal_type)
                .OrderByDescending(c => c.UploadDate);
        }
        if (query.startDate != null)
        {
            data = data.Where(c => c.UploadDate >= query.startDate);
        }
        if (query.endDate != null)
        {
            data = data.Where(c => c.UploadDate <= query.endDate);
        }
        if (!data.Any())
        {
            var message = string.Format("No data was found");
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
    }
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Yes that is correct. If i search (api/test/deal_type=cr), I should get records starting from 2014-01-01 but instead I get cr random records from 2013. is their a function i can use to filter result by order by date? Thank you for your response.

Comment: Look at generated sql-query, it may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try change this:

```
[Queryable(PageSize = 10)]
```

For this:

```
[Queryable(PageSize = 10, EnsureStableOrdering = false)]
```

More informations [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.http.odata.query.odataquerysettings.ensurestableordering%28v=vs.111%29.aspx). 
Hope that helps!

See ya!